Raspberry Pi 5 (Ubuntu) : SSH works intermittently
I run Ubuntu Server on my Raspberry Pi 5, headless install. I always access it by running ssh username@IP_Address.
Sometimes it works flawlessly and I am able to connect to the Pi. However, once I disconnect (e.g. [sudo reboot] or [sudo shutdown -h]) and run the same ssh command, I get error ssh: connect to host (IP_Address) port 22: Operation timed out.
I've tried turning the Pi's power off and on, and removing and reinserting the SD card, but I still can't find a consistent way to ssh to the Pi. What might be causing this behavior, and how might I fix this?

"ssh: connect to host (IP_Address) port 22: Operation timed out" -> Can you ping the Pi at that point?  What happens if you turn the Pi off and try the same thing -- do you get a timeout or "no route to host"?

@goldilocks in the first case, I get the error message ping: sendto: Host is down and also at times a ping: sendto: No route to host. After turning the Pi off, I get the same exact error messages.

So in fact the problem is probably not that ssh doesn't work, it's that the Pi is failing to get back online.  The easiest way to debug that is if you can then connect a screen and keyboard.

Is it possible to keep it headless? I don't have a monitor and am running Ubuntu Server.

You don't need a GUI installed (which is mostly all "Server" means in distro packaging), but obviously you would need a monitor.  You could try things like configuring a direct ethernet connection (ie., hotplug an ethernet cable into it and a laptop) or the serial console but the most foolproof and least fuss is keyboard and monitor.

WRT the error messages: "No route to host" and "Host is down" will happen on a local network when there is a layer 2 address (the MAC, which is necessary) cached on the system, but no response from it, and ARP cannot find another. "Operation timed out" will happen when there's no cached MAC address and ARP cannot find one, hence all of these imply either the other system is not online or a firewall in the middle is dropping packages to or from it.

Unless you've used this same Pi 5 running RPi OS 'bookworm' on your network successfully, then you have "network issues". If you have "network issues", we probably can't help you as that is an "off-topic" question. If you have used this same Pi 5 running RPi OS 'bookworm' on your network, then please edit your question, adding that as a statement.
